# Site not showing CSS

Tags: linux, .htaccess, css

My site http://www.gamer-source.com/ is not showing any CSS on the page.  I see that CSS is indeed loading properly if I visit the URLs.  I've cleared minify's cache so I know that's not the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

style-all.css and article/news/view.css are not being loaded due to bad request errors. Check that their path is correct and valid.

Comment: They have the same permissions as all the other CSS files, and the paths are correct.

Comment: Not sure why but if you use the Firebug plugin with Firefox you will see tho results for those 2 files are 400 Bad Request

Comment: The directory path for minify wasn't pointing to the right place... dangit!